# In Magento observer event, how to redirect to the url "http://www.google.com/" if the url contains "www.example.com"?

Tags: event-observer, redirect

By using magento observer event, I would like to know how to redirect to another url if the url contains "www.example.com" ?
For example,

```
if(url contains "www.example.com")
{
  redirect to "http://www.google.com/"
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Which event do you want to observe?

Comment: Actually, I don't know which observer I have to use. May I know which observer I have to use to catch current url?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

Inside your event observer

```
If ($this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() == "http//www.example.com") {
      $this->_redirectUrl($url)
}
```

Comment: Hi Osrecio, thanks for your code. May I know which observer event can I use to catch current url? Can I use controller_action_predispatch? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can use this observer to get current url before action controller proceed

Comment: This is a performance killer, you will be observing each and every controller load by doing this.

Comment: u're right but do not know what it wants or what its purpose

Comment: so, which observer event can I use because I would like to catch the url. If the url I run on the browser contains "www.example.com", I want to redirect to "www.aaa.com". Thanks!

Comment: You can try this with .htaccess -> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} foobar RewriteRule .* www.aaa.com

Comment: controller_action_predispatch is a perfect fit for an observer to solve this. As long you only do a simple string function/compare its fine, just dont do something heavy/time consuming, or maybe think about caching then.